# Trigger event on the new order in Woo JS

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

How can one listen to "added to card", "coupon applied", "order created", and "order paid" events in woocommerce JS?

For the analytics purposes, I need to listen to these events when triggered, but I don't see how this can be implemented.

Comment: @HUistSebastian yes, and no. Are these events triggered even if somebody uses custom wp theme?

Comment: I didn't look into it myself right now. But generally, these Events should be triggered by the scripts that are loaded by the woocommerce plugin. So yes, they should be triggered on every theme, even custom coded ones.